# Hibernate: how to deal with PropertyAccessException (invalid data)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have an entity with a field of type FOO, but an external process writes the invalid value BAR into the database. So next time I try to read this entity with Hibernate I get an exception like this:

org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [BAR] value by reflection

Unfortunately I also get this exception, when I call the method getAllFoo() and the database contains 999 valid entities plus the one invalid entity. I would like to be able to get the 999 valid entities plus a warning of some sort for the invalid one.

Is that even possible in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 3 options:

(1): Add a `WHERE field IN(<list of valid values>)` clause to all queries to this table+field.

(2): Clean up the database and add a contraint to the field, so that no invalid values can end up in there.

(3): Add the invalid option (I assume it's an enum?) to your entity, and filter it out in own code. This may break proper pagination of queries. It will also get messy quickly if you have a large variety of invalid values.

**Edit**

(4): Create a custom hibernate type (UserType). There you can parse the value manually from the prepared statement / result set. This allows you to (instead of throwing an exception) map 'invalid' values to `null` or any other meaningful value that you can process.

Comment: Good suggestions in general, but in my case there are a few gotchas:

(1) The list of valid values is infinite.

(2) The field is a GEOMETRY (via PostGIS) and can contain any shape (such as POLYGON or LINESTRING or even EMPTY COLLECTION). My entity class expects a LINESTRING, though. So there is no way to validate this in the database, as the GEOMETRY type is too general and internally complex.

(3) Yes, or even make the field in my entity a GEOMETRY and then validate it manually.

But my question was specifically whether the exception can be handled.

Comment: Another idea: Create a custom hibernate type for this field.
And when parsing it (manually, from the result set), map it to `null` when you encounter an invalid value.
This would allow you to keep the result of 999 valid and 1 invalid item, where that field would simply be empty.

I'll update my answer to include this option.

Comment: The UserType is a good idea, because it allows me avoid the exception without sacrificing strong typing in my entity. I'll mark this as answered.